# Xorg crashed with SIGABRT in OsAbort()?

Tags: 16.04, xorg

When I logged in to my system, a pop up appeared and shows your system has experienced an internal error.
When I report the problem and see the crash details it shows

```
Executable path: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg
Package: xserver-xorg-core 2:1.18.4-0ubunty0.7
Title: Xorg crashed with SIGABRT in OsAbort()
ApportVersion: 2.20.1-0ubuntu2.17
```

Along with the above details, it showed many more, If you want more info I can provide that, this error is showing frequently
after 3-4 days interval, anyone can provide the solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my HP Envy running Ubuntu 16.04.  I installed Xorg all video:

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-all
```

This fixed the problem for me.  I tried downloading the video driver specific to my chip set, but I received the same error at start up.